# TiKZ circles not drawn around nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following TiKZ picture:

```tex
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,node distance=24]
        \node (a) {(};
        \node (b) [circle,right of=a] {(};
        \node (c) [right of=b] {(};
        \node (d) [right of=c] {A};
        \node (e) [right of=d] { | };
        \node (f) [right of=e] {B};
        \node (g) [right of=f] {)};
        \node (h) [right of=g] {*};
        \node (i) [right of=h] {|};
        \node (j) [right of=i] {C};
        \node (k) [right of=j] {D};
        \node (l) [right of=k] {*};
        \node (m) [right of=l] {|};
        \node (n) [right of=m] {E};
        \node (o) [right of=n] {F};
        \node (p) [right of=o] {G};
        \node (q) [right of=p] {)};
        \node (r) [right of=q] {*};
        \node (s) [right of=r] {)};
        \node (t) [right of=s] {*};

        \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (a) edge node {} (b);
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (b) edge node {} (c);
        \path[->] (c) edge node {} (d);
        \path[->,bend right] (c) edge node {} (f);
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (d) edge node {} (e);
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red,bend left] (e) edge node {} (g);
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (f) edge node {} (g);
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (g) edge node {} (h);
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red,bend right] (h) edge node {} (c);
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red,bend right] (c) edge node {} (h);
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (h) edge node {} (i);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

This gives me this output, which is close to what I'd like, but I'd like to circle each `\node` so that the arrows are clearer.
[image: screenshot]

Changing each `\node` to `\node[circle]` does nothing. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution: use `draw` to visualize the circle.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{mycirc}=[draw, circle, inner sep=2pt]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,node distance=24]
        \node (a) [mycirc,] {(};
        \node (b) [mycirc,right of=a] {(};
        \node (c) [mycirc,right of=b] {(};
        \node (d) [mycirc,right of=c] {A};
        \node (e) [mycirc,right of=d] { | };
        \node (f) [mycirc,right of=e] {B};
        \node (g) [mycirc,right of=f] {)};
        \node (h) [mycirc,right of=g] {*};
        \node (i) [mycirc,right of=h] {|};
        \node (j) [mycirc,right of=i] {C};
        \node (k) [mycirc,right of=j] {D};
        \node (l) [mycirc,right of=k] {*};
        \node (m) [mycirc,right of=l] {|};
        \node (n) [mycirc,right of=m] {E};
        \node (o) [mycirc,right of=n] {F};
        \node (p) [mycirc,right of=o] {G};
        \node (q) [mycirc,right of=p] {)};
        \node (r) [mycirc,right of=q] {*};
        \node (s) [mycirc,right of=r] {)};
        \node (t) [mycirc,right of=s] {*};
        
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (a) edge node {} (b);
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (b) edge node {} (c);
        \path[->] (c) edge node {} (d);
        \path[->,bend right] (c) edge node {} (f);
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (d) edge node {} (e);
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red,bend left] (e) edge node {} (g);
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (f) edge node {} (g);
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (g) edge node {} (h);
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red,bend right] (h) edge node {} (c);
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red,bend right] (c) edge node {} (h);
        \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (h) edge node {} (i);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question has already been given in [Excelsior's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595160/241086). This is just to mention that you do not have to painstakingly add all the nodes by hand, you can use a chain, and some parser that decomposes a sequence of characters into nodes. The whole chain is then obtained with

```
 \begin{scope}[start chain=going right,nodes={on chain,circle,draw}]
  \tikzset{my parse={(((A|B)*|CD*|EFG)*)*}}
 \end{scope}
```

as in

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,chains}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{my parse/.code={\expandafter\mytikzcparse@i#1\pgfmath@token@stop}}
\def\mytikzcparse@i#1#2\pgfmath@token@stop{%
\node[alias=\@alph\tikzchaincount]{{$#1$}};%
\def\pgfutil@tmpa{#2}%
\unless\ifx\pgfutil@tmpa\empty
\expandafter\mytikzcparse@i#2\pgfmath@token@stop
\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[bend]}]
 \begin{scope}[start chain=going right,nodes={on chain,circle,draw}]
  \tikzset{my parse={(((A|B)*|CD*|EFG)*)*}}
 \end{scope} 
 \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (a) to (b);
 \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (b) to (c);
 \path[->] (c) to (d);
 \path[->,bend right] (c) to (f);
 \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (d) to (e);
 \path[->,draw=black!30!red,bend left] (e) to (g);
 \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (f) to (g);
 \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (g) to (h);
 \path[->,draw=black!30!red,bend right] (h) to (c);
 \path[->,draw=black!30!red,bend right] (c) to (h);
 \path[->,draw=black!30!red] (h) to (i); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]